# Success Response from SQL Result to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I've a php file in which I've the below codes to denote the success and failure of a particular sql query.

```
if(!$update_val)
        {
            // die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
            die(json_encode(array('result' => false , 'message' => 'Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error()))); 

        }

        // echo "Entered data successfully\n";
            echo json_encode(array('result' => true , 'message' => 'Entered data successfully'));
```

To cater to this response and to display the **response message on the same page** I've the following javascript function:

```
$(function () 
{
    $('form').submit(function (e) 
    {                   
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#please_wait_info').show();
        document.getElementById("thankyou_info").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("sorry_info").style.display = "none";
        console.error('\nInside javascript loop!\n');

        $.ajax(
        {
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (response) 
            {
                console.log(response);                          
                if(response.result == true)  
                {
                    document.getElementById("thankyou_info").style.display = "inline";
                    document.getElementById("form_link").style.display = "inline";
                    $('#please_wait_info').hide();
                    document.getElementById("info-form").reset();
                    console.error('Inside success loop!\n');
                }

                else 
                {           
                    document.getElementById("thankyou_info").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("sorry_info").style.display = "inline";
                    $('#please_wait_info').hide();  
                    console.error('Inside error loop!\n');
                }   
            }
        });
        console.error('Outside error loop!\n');
    });
});
```

**Edit**: With the addition of `dataType: 'json'`, the program is now skipping the `$.ajax()` function altogether.

The problem with the above (2nd)code is that it always results in the execution of the `else` statement.

Can you please suggest me what do I check in the `if` statement (i.e. in the `if(response.result == ?)`) to satisfy the success criteria?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're expecting a json object as response from server, add `dataType: 'json'` setting in your AJAX request.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul However on mention of `dataType: 'json'` makes the program skip the `$.ajax()` function altogether. Can you suggest why this is happening?

Comment: Edit your question with the updated code snippet(s) so that we could see you did/change in the code.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul code snippet updated.

Comment: I don't see anything that could generate such behavior. Do `alert(response.message);` inside both of your `if` and `else` block, `if(response.result == true){ ... }else { ... }`. Although you included `dataType: 'json'` correctly in your code, but in **Edit**, it didn't get reflected correctly, `dataType: 'json`(missing single quote). Also, what makes you believe that it's skipping `$.ajax()` completely?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul The addition of `alert(response.message);` in both `if` and `else` statements did not result in an alert response. I'm saying that it's skipping `$.ajax()` because I can see only two responses (as embedded in the code itself) in the console: `console.error('\nInside javascript loop!\n');` and `console.error('Outside error loop!\n');`, nothing in between.